# ctest --output-on-failure and setting CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE don't work

Tags: cmake, ctest

[According to the documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/ctest.1.html), the `--output-on-failure` argument will instruct ctest to show the tests output when they fail. A second approach is to set the env var `CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE`. Neither option work for me.

As you can see on [appveyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/vinipsmaker/boost-http/build/1.0.63/job/71vy3hxrx9clstju#L1028), some tests fail, but no output is given.

On GNU/Linux, setting the `CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE` does work for me.

I am using CMake version 3.2.3-win32-x86.

Comment: I filled a bug on CMake about this issue: http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=15615

Comment: Ran into the same issue on appveyor, but it turned out that on windows, a dialog box was popping up warning about missing DLLs, so there was no console output to be shown except for `*** Exception: Other`.